# Quicksort algorithm printing a segmentation fault, not working properly

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I am currently working on a quicksort algorithm that takes in random doubles, ints, char, and floats. Currently testing the doubles and I am getting `(process 27368) exited with code -1073740791`. I do know this is a segment fault, but I am not seeing an issue with what I have. The code is in C++. Here it is:

```
// Code for generating random doubles
vector<double> generateDouble(int size, double min, double max)
{
    srand(time(0));
    vector<double> array(size);

    for (int index = 0; index < size; ++index)
    {
        double r = (((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) * (max - min)) + min;
        array[index] = r;
    }

    return array;
}
```

```
// here is the getIter() function
int Sorting::getIter() const
{
    return iter;
}
```

```
void Sorting::quickSort()
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = listData.size() - 1;
    quickSort(listData, first, last);
}

void Sorting::quickSort(vector<double>& list, int first, int last)
{
    if (first < last)
    {
        int index = partition(list, first, last);

        quickSort(list, first, index - 1);
        quickSort(list, index + 1, last); // Corrected index
    }
}

int Sorting::partition(vector<double>& list, int first, int last)
{
    double pivot = list[last - 1];
    int i = first - 1; // Initialize i with first instead of (first - 1)

    for (int j = first; j < last; j++)
    {
        if (list[j] < pivot)
        {
            // Increment i before swapping
            i++;
            swap(list[i], list[j]);
        }
        iter++;
    }
    // Swap pivot with the element at (i + 1)
    swap(list[i], list[last - 1]);
    return i;
}
```

```
// how I am calling it in main

Sorting quickDSort(dd);
time.startTimer();
quickDSort.quickSort();
time.stopTimer();
cout << "(quick sort) Double Iterations: " << quickDSort.getIter() << endl;
cout << time.getSeconds() << endl;
```

I have been stuck for a while, not sure what too do. Thanks.

I need the code to take the `vector<double>` and sort it. With that I have currently, it does not print the amount of times it takes to sort the numbers.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? That's something you could do when you're not sure what to do.

Comment: With segfaults on simple programs, you don't even need to know that much. Just running the program through the debugger and seeing the crash should generate a stack trace and give you a starting point, if not outright identify the problem area.

Comment: this is what it is saying "An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal." But it is also going through the for loop a lot.

Comment: I just fixed it! It had something to do wth my `double pivot` and my `int i` as well as how I was swapping the last element of `'list`

Answer (score 1):

It is strange to see comments in your code that do not relate to what you actually *do*.

For instance,

```
    // Swap pivot with the element at (i + 1)
    swap(list[i], list[last - 1]);
```

...You're *not* swapping with the element at `(i + 1)`, and actually you *should*.

Secondly, the last element in current subarray is not at `last-1`, but at `last`. So also that index is wrong, both in the code quoted above, as at the start of the `partition` function.

Here is your `partition` function with those bugs corrected:

```
int partition(vector<double>& list, int first, int last)
{
    double pivot = list[last]; // Should be last, not last-1
    int i = first - 1;

    for (int j = first; j < last; j++)
    {
        if (list[j] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            swap(list[i], list[j]);
        }
    }
    i++; // Must increment
    swap(list[i], list[last]); // Should be last, not last-1
    return i;
}
```